# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{3^n}$

Tags: calculus, limits

As stated in the question, I'm trying to find the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{3^n}$$

This is my attempt:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n}{3^n}
= \lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{3^n}$$

The first limit pulls to $\infty$ whereas the second limit pulls to
$0$ and hence the limit will be $0$. Is the justfication right ?

Is there any other way to solve it ?

Comment: That is incorrect. You can only separate limits if each exists (read: is a real number) individually.

Comment: While your conclusion is correct the reasoning is not. Pulling apart the expression in two limits is not a good idea and the $=$ sign you've written down is actually incorrect.

Comment: @Integrand Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't consider that.

Comment: @Sibi Even if you could seperate the limits it doesn't make any sense to say $\infty\cdot0=0$ because this is a well known indeterminate form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Claim: for $n\geq 1$, $n/2<(3/2)^n$. The claim is immediate for $n=1$ and follows by induction: the LHS increases by $1/2$ as $n$ increases to $n+1$ and the RHS increases by at least $3/4$ (by much more, in fact, but this is sufficient).

Then $0 <(2/3)^n<2/n$, and $2/n\to 0$. By the Squeeze Theorem, $(2/3)^n\to 0$.

Comment: Noce answer. The claim is true for any $n \in \Bbb {N}$ I have already upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 9):

Let $r\in(0,1)$. Then the sequence $a_{n} = r^{n}$ is bounded below by zero and it is decreasing. Thus it converges.

Moreover, we have that
\begin{align*}
L = \lim_{n\to\infty}r^{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}r\times r^{n} = r\lim_{n\to\infty}r^{n} = rL \Rightarrow L(1 - r) = 0
\end{align*}
Since $r\in(0,1)$, we conclude that $L = 0$. At your case, $r = 2/3$.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $\frac{2^n}{3^n}$ as $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ and say that the limit is 0 as $\frac{2}{3}<1$.

Comment: I don't like this answer because you seem to be applying the fact that $|a|\lt1\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}a^n=0$ which is much stronger than the OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

Other way in general terms is:
If $0<a<1$, then:
Take $$y=\lim_{n\to \infty}a^n$$
$$\ln{y}=\lim_{n\to \infty}n\ln(a)$$
How $\ln(a)<0$, then
$$\ln{y}\to-\infty$$
$$y\to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive approach would be to observe that $3^n/2^n = (1.5)^n$  tends to $\infty$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

So $1/(1.5)^n$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.